# How can I make sure users can't run my macro after a specific date?

Tags: vba

Is there a way to restrain a macro accessibility? I want to sell the macro. give it to another person to use it, but I need to make sure that it does not run after ten times of runs or after a specific date! So they would be forced to pay for the registration. One more thing is that it is not for excel.

Comment: If you called it from another module you could remove the other module programatically. I've not tried this in the exact way you describe so I don't know if after it had been deleted you might get syntax issues.

Comment: You could just use a For Loop and run it 10 times within the loop.  Or, If this is from Excel, you could store the number of times run in a cell and prevent it from running if the cell value is greater than or equal to 10.

Comment: I read this as the OP wanting to physically remove the capability for it to be run. Maybe clarification could be given?

Answer (score 2):

This procedure will only run 10 times, but be warned, if the VBA project is reset, it will be run another 10 times.

```
Sub RunMe()

  Static NumberOfRuns As Long

  If NumberOfRuns < 10 Then
    NumberOfRuns = NumberOfRuns + 1
    'Do the stuff that needs doing here
    Debug.Print NumberOfRuns
  End If

End Sub
```